# OCMock stub with args not returning expected value

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I'm trying to write unit tests for https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor and I'm having some trouble.

In Xcode I'm trying to use OCMock (and Specta, Expecta) to test the getVideoInfo method. Part of this method creates an AVURLAsset and retrieves an array of tracks from it.

In this example test I'm trying to stub the tracksWithMediaType method. I've tried several variations but with no luck. Outcomes have ranged from EXC_BAD_ACCESS exceptions to tests crashing and tests simply failing.

```
avAssetTrack = OCMClassMock([AVAssetTrack class]);
        
id mockAVURLAssetClass = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AVURLAsset class]];
        [[[mockAVURLAssetClass stub] andReturn:@[avAssetTrack]] tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://fakepath"];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        
        // Above is not enough. Try stubbing the instance.
        NSArray *array = @[avAssetTrack];
        OCMStub([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]).andReturn(array);
        
        NSArray *tracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        
        //OCMStub([avURLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]).andReturn(@[avAssetTrack]);
        // This casuses EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using OCM Stub above? Why?
        //NSArray *tracks = [avURLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        
        expect([tracks objectAtIndex:0]).to.equal(avAssetTrack);
```

The returned tracks array is empty so the test fails.

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to OCMock but I've been reading through documentation, tutorials, and or SO posts without much luck toward resolving this.

Comment: Can you please include the code you want to test in the question?

Comment: Why are you using `OCMStub` on an invocation where the receiver, `asset` in this case, is not a mock? What do you expect that that achieves? And in the Stub call that's commented out, where does `avURLAsset` come from?